# How write not null in primary key in the schema in sqlite file using sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I'm doing a project in which i am using nodejs , seqelize and sqlite3 ,

I am generating the sqlite file schema using sequelize,

but i have problem in the primary key ,

the sqlite file generated but the primary key allow null ,

how can write not null in the primary key ?

I wrote allowNull: false in sequelize schema .

This is the model schema :

```
/* jshint indent: 2 */

module.exports = function(sequelizeModule, sequelize) {
  return sequelizeModule.define('agents_locations', {
    id: {
      type: sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    agent_id: {
      type: sequelize.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false
    },
    location_id: {
      type: sequelize.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'agents_locations'
  });
};
```

I expect the primary key not null , but it is allow null

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but if your issue is that the column def for `id` does not contain the `NOT NULL` clause, then it does not need to: it is redundant with the primary key constraint (a kprimary key can not be NULL).

Comment: Your code should work as expected. Maybe you want set id value automatically, if so just add  autoIncrement: true

Comment: Den Rupp for the requirements i got in the project the primary key can not be autoIncrement

Comment: Den Rupp for the requirements i got in the project the primary key can not be autoIncrement